# Windows 10 Preview running on mac mini expired - unable to boot

Tags: mac, windows-10, bios, boot-camp, osx-yosemite

I was running Windows 10 Preview on my mac mini using bootcamp.  Now when I start my computer I am unable to boot into Windows 10 and I'm getting the following error message:  Your PC/Device Needs to be Repaired. A component of your operating system has expired.

I did some online research and came across [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjsAy0zBh1g) that direct one to boot into bios and change the date.  Unfortunately,  when I try to boot into the bios by hitting the delete key during the restart I go right back to the error message and not into bios.

Does anyone have a fix for this.  I'm happy to purchase Windows 10, but at this point I'm just dead in the water and concerned I'm going to lose some very important files.

Comment: It's not clear from the wording why you can't just buy Windows 10, as you say you are willing to do. What's stopping you from doing so?

Comment: There is no BIOS as such on Macs. Maybe command+shift+S will get you into the EFI, from where you should be able to set the date. At a rough guess, `date 20151001` *might* be of use.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton What i mean, is that I'm stuck at this error message and if I were to just buy window how I would install it (without losing my data).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Interesting that you day that.   One thing I tried was to boot into Yosemite and change the date to 10/1/15.  Then I rebooted and the system booted into a windows screen that game me the option to restart or advanced option. I chose restart, but perhaps I will try advance options next time.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor It might be necessary to ensure that the computer cannot connect to the Internet while you are making adjustments, otherwise it may automatically set the actual current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy windows 10 online on another computer and download the version for USB install. Follow the instructions on creating a bootable USB stick(make sure you don't need any of the data on the stick as it will be erased). Finally boot the Mac from the stick :)